# RegEx for matching two digits and everything except new lines and dot

Tags: python, regex

Using python v3, I'm trying to find a string only if it contains one to two digits (and not anymore than that in the same number) along with everything else following it. The match breaks on periods or new lines.

`\d{1,2}[^.\n]+`  is almost right except it returns numbers greater than two digits.

For example:

```
"5+years {} experience. stop. 

10 asdasdas   . 255 

1abc1 

5555afasfasf++++s()(jn."
```

Should return:

```
5+years {} experience

10 asdasdas   

1abc1
```

Comment: `'(\d[^\d][^.\n]+|\d\d[^\d][^.\n]+)'` seems to get closer to what you're looking for, except that it also matches `55afasfasf++++s()(2jn` when I do `re.findall()`. This is just literally specifying "I want either one digit or two digits". There's probably a fairly simple way to get it to ignore cases where there are more than two, but idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your description and your sample data, you can use following regex to match the intended strings and discard others,

```
^\d[^\d.]*\d?[^\d.\n]*(?=\.|$)
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of line
- `\d` - Matches a digit
- `[^\d.]*` - This matches any character other than digit or dot zero or more times. This basically allows optionally matching of non-digit non-dot characters.
- `\d?` - As you want to allow one or two digits, this is the second digit which is optional hence `\d` followed by `?`
- `[^\d.\n]*` - This matches any character other than digit or dot or newline
- `(?=\.|$)` - This positive look ahead ensures, the match either ends with a dot or end of line

Also, notice, multiline mode is enabled as `^` and `$` need to match start of line and end of line.ad

**[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/lMJlTo/2/)**

#### Code:

```
import re

s = '''5+years {} experience. stop.

10 asdasdas . 255

1abc1

5555afasfasf++++s()(2jn.'''

print(re.findall(r'(?m)^\d[^\d.]*\d?[^\d.\n]*(?=\.|$)', s))
```

#### Prints:

```
['5+years {} experience', '10 asdasdas ', '1abc1']
```

Also, if matching lines doesn't necessarily start with digits, you can use this regex to capture your intended string but here you need to get your string from group1 if you want captured string to start with number only, and if intended string doesn't necessarily have to start with digits, then you can capture whole match.

```
^[^\d\n]*(\d[^\d.]*\d?[^\d.\n]*)(?=\.|$)
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of line
- `[^\d\n]*` - Allows zero or more non-digit characters before first digit
- `(` - Starts first grouping pattern to capture the string starting with first digit
- `\d` - Matches a digit
- `[^\d.]*` - This matches any character other than digit or dot zero or more times. This basically allows optionally matching of non-digit non-dot characters.
- `\d?` - As you want to allow one or two digits, this is the second digit which is optional hence `\d` followed by `?`
- `[^\d.\n]*` - This matches any character other than digit or dot or newline
- `) - End of first capturing pattern
- `(?=\.|$)` - This positive look ahead ensures, the match either ends with a dot or end of line

Multiline mode is enabled which you can enable by placing `(?m)` before start of regex also called inline modifier or by passing third argument to `re.search` as `re.MULTILINE`

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lMJlTo/3)**

#### Code:

```
import re

s = '''5+years {} experience. stop.

10 asdasdas . 255

1abc1

aaa1abc1

aa2aa1abc1

5555afasfasf++++s()(2jn.'''

print(re.findall(r'(?m)^[^\d\n]*(\d[^\d.]*\d?[^\d.\n]*)(?=\.|$)', s))
```

#### Prints:

```
['5+years {} experience', '10 asdasdas ', '1abc1', '1abc1']
```

Comment: Sorry, let me add explanation, after that it should appear simple.